# How to find a specific text block in a log file using PowerShell and RegExp?

Tags: regex, powershell, logging

I need a little help with defining the RegExp part in my Powershell script. The log looks like this:

```
*** Start ***
<log>Nope<log>
*** End ***
*** Start ***
<log>Gotcha<log>
*** End ***
*** Start ***
<log>Nope<log>
*** End ***
*** Start ***
<log>Nope<log>
*** End ***
```

I'd like to use Regexp to extract every block, which starts with: `*** Start ***`, ends with: `*** End ***` and in between there is a match to the string "Gotcha". The result should look like this:

```
*** Start ***
<log>Gotcha<log>
*** End ***
```

Unfortunately I'm just learning RegExp, and this far I got, but it's not working well... it shows the whole text:

`(\*\*\*\ Start \*\*\*)((?:.|\n)*)\bGotcha((?:.|\n)*)(\*\*\*\ End \*\*\*)`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
(\*{3} Start \*{3}[^*]*\bGotcha\b[^*]*\*{3} End \*{3})
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/eQ7gT7/1)

- `\*{3} Start \*{3}` match the `*` character literally 3 times followed by 'Start', then `*` literally 3 times again.
- `[^*]*\bGotcha\b[^*]*` Select all none `*` character that contain the string 'Gotcha' somewhere in between.
- `\*{3} End \*{3}` match the `*` character literally 3 times followed by 'End', then `*` literally 3 times again.

It would capture:

```
*** Start ***
<log>Gotcha<log>
*** End ***
```

Alternatively, just in case the inner text contains a `*` character, you could also use:

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/tC1cL1/1)

```
(\*{3} Start \*{3}\n.*\bGotcha\b.*\n\*{3} End \*{3})
```

Comment: It works very well, thank You for the fast response!